# Forcing Databricks SQL Style Permissions even For Data engineering and machine learning personas

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I, as an admin, would like users to be forced to use Databricks SQL style permissions model, even in the Data Engineering and Machine Learning profiles.

In Databricks SQL, I have a data access policy set , which my sql endpoint/warehouse uses and schemas have permissions assigned to groups. Users query data through the endpoint and see what they have access to. So, that works fine.

I would like the same to happen in Data Engineering and Machine Learning personas.

As a first step, I have setup a cluster policy which defines the spark configs (in secret scopes which connects to the datalake) and also forces table ACL.
The problem is the non admins, don;t have rights to read from the secret scopes.

Is there a way, where I can still have the flexibility for them to create their own clusters, through a defined cluster policy and still force table ACLs?

Most of the docs I have read, seems to point out that I have to explicitly create the cluster for them to use (a Shared cluster).

Is there no way around this.

E.g. this is how my first attempt at a cluster policy looked like (mimicking the data access policy of a SQL endpoint)

```
{
  "cluster_type": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "all-purpose"
  },
  "num_workers": {
    "type": "range",
    "maxValue": 4,
    "isOptional": true
  },
  "autotermination_minutes": {
    "type": "range",
    "minValue": 1,
    "maxValue": 60,
    "defaultValue": 60
  },
  "autoscale.max_workers": {
    "type": "range",
    "maxValue": 4,
    "isOptional": true
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.databricks.acl.dfAclsEnabled": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "true"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "python,sql"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.databricks.cluster.profile": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "serverless"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.datalake.dfs.core.windows.net": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "OAuth"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.datalake.dfs.core.windows.net": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.datalake.dfs.core.windows.net": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "{{secrets/SQLEndpoint/ClientID}}"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.datalake.dfs.core.windows.net": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "{{secrets/SQLEndpoint/ClientSecret}}"
  },
  "spark_conf.spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.datalake.dfs.core.windows.net": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/123456/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

But of course the problem is, they (non admins), don't have rights to read the secret scopes used to connect to the datalake and therefore the creation of cluster fails.
i.e. no read rights on

```
{{secrets/SQLEndpoint/ClientSecret}}
```

Is there no way then that they can create their own clusters (through a defined policy) and yet have databricks sql style permissions?

Is the only way out is that I create a Shared Cluster beforehand for them to use?

Comment: Cluster owner should have access to the secret... You can create clusters for your users, and give them `CAN_MANAGE` permission - in this case you'll be cluster owner so it will be able to read secret

Comment: Thanks. So, as it seems, like I asked in my question, creating a cluster beforehand for them is the only option (shared or per user but created by an admin(me) )

Comment: Or maybe somehow call this , after they have created the cluster - https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/clusters/changeowner

Comment: this may not work because cluster manager will try to read secret and create operation fail if they don't have access to it.

Comment: What I have found is they are able to create the cluster , just that it does not start up , because it fails while reading the secret. I can see their failed cluster. Therefore I was thinking of something where they create the cluster (without starting) and then request for a run of a pipeline, which will have the cluster id as a variable and then admins approve the run of the pipeline. The script which gets executed on the run of the pipeline will basically change the owner to a workspace admin (the spn which actually does the deployment).

Comment: this may work, although I didn't try. But if it requires running of a pipeline that is approved by admins, what is the difference with creating clusters for users explicitly?

Comment: I think the difference is then the same admins do not have to create clusters each time a new user is onboarded. It is upto the user and they follow steps and request for the run of the pipeline. This then automatically sends out notifications to e.g teams channel which admins monitor and all they do is click approve. Also, each user generally has one cluster. So, for the most part , no duplication of effort and the admins only approve when they get a notification which is standard as they do the same for any standard pull request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have mentioned it in the comments, just formalizing the answer here.

So, there are 2 solutions:

1. First solution- The admin creates the cluster with the Cluster policy (that I referred in my question above), for each new user. The downside of this method is the admin becomes the bottleneck, before a user can get started.
2. Second solution- The user (non admin) creates the cluster. The cluster would fail to start up, but would get created anyways. The user can then request a run of a pipeline (azure devops in my case), by passing a parameter for the clusterid of his/her newly created cluster. This pipeline would basically change the owner of the cluster to that of an admin. You may/may not choose to have an approval process around this process. Even if there is an approval process, you can have a teams hook, posting to a channel, which anyone from the approver group can approve (they don't even have to be the Databricks admin. Just anyone, listed in the approver groups of the devops pipeline. This pipeline, in my case, calls a powershell script ,which basically does :  [this](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/clusters/changeowner). This basically only changes the owner of the cluster to a databricks admin. The non admin user, who created the cluster would continue to have the "can manage" permissions on the cluster. I have tested it- and the non admin user, can only select from tables he/she has access to. The owner change only helps in reading the secrets, during the cluster startup stage. I have also verified, that the non admin, can't also read the secrets. so, all in all, it works, without the Databricks admin being a bottleneck.